# Using actionListener with Button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am programming a menu to be used with a formerly all text based game. I am trying to use addActionListener to print a line of text when a button is clicked, so I can figure out how to implement my main code in the future. The issue I am having is with the addActionListener method on my JButton. I am performing all of this with a JFrame. From what others say, I have used this as the argument but am getting a "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" error. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu
{



    public static void Menu()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click to enter");
        button.setBounds(125, 140, 150, 20);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Casino");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        @Override
        String s = "Welcome!";
        System.out.println(s);    
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use static variables and methods unless you know what you are doing. Don't just randomly start coding a GUI program. Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are plenty of examples that will show you how to create and structure your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your program is nothing more than a single static method with everything trying to be shoehorned into this method. This would be fine if you were creating the most basic console program, such as one that asks the user for 2 numbers, then adds the numbers and returns the answer, but you are no longer trying to do this. Instead you're trying to create a Swing GUI program, one whose state you wish to change if the user interacts with it in an event-driven way, in other words you want it to change state if the user presses a button or selects a menu item.

Your problem is that you're trying to mesh this simple static world with the "instance" world, but in static land, there is no `this`.

Since your needs and requirements are becoming more complex, your program structure will need to change to reflect this. Is this an absolute requirement that you do this? No -- something called Turing Equivalence tells that it is possible to write most complex program imaginable inside of a single static main method, but due to the increased complexity, the program would become very difficult to understand and almost impossible to debug.

What I recommend specifically is that you create one or more well behaved object-orient classes, classes with non-static variables and non-static methods, and use these to build your GUI and its model (the non-GUI nucleus that GUI programs should have). Again the main method should be short, very short, and should only involve itself in creating the above classes, and setting the GUI visible, and that's about it.

What you want to do is to study the basic concepts of Java, and in particular that on how to create Java classes. The Java tutorials can help you with this.

Comment: I can't believe you typed all that :P

Comment: Keep it stored in the clipboard, I think you'll need it again soon ;)

Comment: gift from God, a gift to write and comprehensible to all

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with this class.

1. It does not implement `ActionListener` so it can't be used as parameter to `JButton`
2. The static modifier on the `Menu` method means you can even use `this` anyway
3. `public static void Main` is not a constructor, so beware
4. `@Override` should appear before the method declaration, not in it.

Something like...

```
public class Menu implements ActionListener
{

    public Menu()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Click to enter");
        button.setBounds(125, 140, 150, 20);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Casino");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s = "Welcome!";
        System.out.println(s);    
    }
}
```

Might be a better approach, but I'd be worried about creating a `JFrame` within the class, but that's just me...

Comment: I added the missing "implements ActionListener" in Menu class. Hope you don't mind. :)